# Model.Classify() gives GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Object cannot be used because it has not been generated

Tags: tensorflow.js

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1384#issue-421174127

**TensorFlow.js version**
1.0.0

**Browser version**
Google Chrome: Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**Describe the problem or feature request**

I followed the steps from Google Codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html#0

The given example works fine, but when I made some changes to the example for my Blog with multiple images, it gives this error:
[image]

As you can see, when I click on the first image, it works fine. Loads the model, does classification, displays the results. As I click on a second image, it gives these errors. This seems to be happening on this Windows Laptop [Dell Inspiron, Windows 10] with this Version of Chrome only as I am also testing the same thing on a MacBook Pro with the exact same version of Chrome without any errors.

**Code to reproduce the bug/link to feature request**

You can check my Blog here [https://anujdutt9.github.io/TFjs-ImageClassifier.html] and look for errors in the console. Also, you can find the complete code for this here [https://github.com/anujdutt9/anujdutt9.github.io/blob/master/TFjs-ImageClassifier.html].

Comment: Please try to narrow down your issue by giving a simple code. You can have a look at the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am getting the same error 

[.WebGL-00000154029A84F0] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Object cannot be used because it has not been generated.

on 

Chrome 73.0.3683.75 on Windows 10

for pretty much everything including the demos

https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-vis/mnist/dist/index.html

but on

Chrome 75 (Canary) and all other browsers there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by using an updated version of TensorFlow.js. Take a look at the code with the update here: https://github.com/anujdutt9/anujdutt9.github.io/blob/master/TFjs-ImageClassifier.html